# Errno::ENOENT in home#index with ExecJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I just created a sample Rails project running in Windows and ran `rails s`, which ran fine for setup. Later, I created a resource called `resources :crm` and generated the necessary components. I ran into this error that is quite bugging me much. I tried degrading ExecJS but no avail. I also installed Node.js, but that didn't work either. Here is the error log:

```
Showing C:/Users/Rodrigo Argumedo/projects/CRM/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/Rodrigo Argumedo/AppData/Local/Temp/execjs20150622-2296-sj99kvjson

Rails.root: C:/Users/Rodrigo Argumedo/projects/CRM
```

> Is there a solution to this? If so, guide me where to fix this particular error?

EDIT:

**Application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sample Rails</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the line #6 in your `application.html.erb`?

Comment: Question edited. See above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a ExecJS problem and forced to run `bundle install -f` to reinstall the gems and it worked again.